# transition only when checking/unchecking checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox

I'm learning how to make a site and decided to make a dark mode checkbox for it. I set a transition: 0.5s ease-in-out to make it look good but the problem is that the transition occurs everytime I change pages and it hurts the eyes. How can I make it so that the transition only happens when I check or uncheck the checkbox.

```js
const darkBtn = document.querySelector('.fas');
const bodyEl = document.querySelector('body');

const darkMode = () => {
    bodyEl.classList.toggle('dark')
}

darkBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Get the value of the "dark" item from the local storage on every click
    setDarkMode = localStorage.getItem('dark');

    if(setDarkMode !== "on") {
        darkMode();
        // Set the value of the item to "on" when dark mode is on
        setDarkMode = localStorage.setItem('dark', 'on');
    } else {
        darkMode();
        // Set the value of the item to  "null" when dark mode if off
        setDarkMode = localStorage.setItem('dark', null);
    }
});

// Get the value of the "dark" item from the local storage
let setDarkMode = localStorage.getItem('dark');

// Check dark mode is on or off on page reload
if(setDarkMode === 'on') {
    darkMode();
}
```

```css
:root {
      --body-color: #fff;
      --heading-color: #1e202a;
      --text-color: #1e202a;
}

* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
}

body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: Poppins;
      font-weight: 400;
      /* background: url(background-img.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover; */
      background-color: var(--body-color);
      transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav {
      padding: 8px;
}

.logo {
      float: left;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-left: 16px;
      margin-top: 8px;
}

.logo a {
      color: #000;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 18px;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

nav ul {
      float: right;
}

nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
}

nav ul li:not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: 48px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
      margin-right: 24px;
}

nav ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      outline: none;
      color: var(--text-color);
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 1.2px;
      font-weight: 600;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 864px) {
      .logo {
            padding: 0;
      }

      .nav-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
            background: var(--body-color);
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
            color: var(--text-color);
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            width: 100%;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li {
            display: block;
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: right;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(1) a {
            transition-delay: 0s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(2) a {
            transition-delay: 0.1s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(3) a {
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(4) a {
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(5) a {
            transition-delay: 0.4s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:nth-child(6) a {
            transition-delay: 0.5s;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
            margin-left: 0;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li a {
            padding: 10px 24px;
            opacity: 0;
            color: var(--text-color);
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 1.2px;
            transform: translateX(-20px);
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
      }

      .nav-wrapper ul li i {
            padding-right: 35px;
      }

      .nav-btn {
            position: fixed;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            display: block;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 9999;
            border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .nav-btn i {
            display: block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 2px;
            background: var(--text-color);
            border-radius: 2px;
            margin-left: 14px;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
            margin-top: 16px;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
            margin-top: 4px;
            opacity: 1;
      }

      .nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
            margin-top: 4px;
      }
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i {
      background: var(--text-color);
      transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(6px) rotate(180deg);
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
}

#nav:checked+.nav-btn i:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(90deg);
}

#nav:checked~.nav-wrapper {
      z-index: 9990;
      opacity: 1;
}

#nav:checked~.nav-wrapper ul li a {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
}

.hidden {
      display: none;
}

.dark {
      --body-color: #1f212e;
      --heading-color: #8b97c6;
      --text-color: #fff;
}

.fas {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: var(--heading-color);
      transform: rotate(-25deg);
}

.text {
      padding-top: 20%;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-right: 25%;
      margin-left: 25%;
      line-height: 1.8;
      letter-spacing: 0em;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

p {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-right: 25%;
      margin-left: 25%;
      line-height: 1.8;
      letter-spacing: 0em;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

h1 {
      font-family: "Futura-pt", sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top: 100px;
      color: var(--text-color);
      /* color: var(--heading-color); */
}

a {
      color: var(--text-color);
      text-decoration: inherit;
      font-family: "Futura-pt", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      line-height: 1.3;
      letter-spacing: 0em;
}

iframe {
      margin-left: 30%;
      margin-top: 3%;
}

table {
      margin-left: 25%;
      font-family: "Futura-pt", sans-serif;
}

th {
      padding: 1.4em;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

td {
      color: var(--text-color);
}

.lol {
      text-align: center;
}

.skins {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
}

caption {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 2%;
      font-family: "Futura-pt", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

.classes {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      text-align: center;
}

.hobbit {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-left: 290px;
      line-height: 1.8;
      letter-spacing: 0em;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

.homelinks {
      margin-left: 45%;
      line-height: 1.8;
}

.box {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      margin-left: -5%;
}

.box2 {
      position: relative;
      float: right;
      width: 25%;
      margin-right: 30%;
}

.undervids {
      padding-top: 360px;
}

.sidemoon {
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
}

figcaption {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.imgContainer {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 50px;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

.imgContainer2 {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 20px;
      color: var(--text-color);
}

figure {
      text-align: center;
}

.lofivideos {
      text-align: center;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
            <nav>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden">
                  <label for="nav" class="nav-btn">
                        <i></i>
                        <i></i>
                        <i></i>
                  </label>
                  <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html">SITE</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="nav-wrapper">
                        <ul>
                              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                              <li><a href="Lofi.html">Lofi</a></li>
                              <li><a href="League_Of_Legends.html">LoL</a></li>
                              <!-- <li><a href="The_Hobbit.html">The Hobbit</a></li> -->
                              <li><a href="Tower_Of_God.html">ToG</a></li>
                              <li><a href="card.html">Contact</a></li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>
            </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae fugiat, velit, numquam totam vel sequi tempora, rerum nam earum repudiandae omnis consequuntur incidunt! Quam maxime quibusdam neque corporis tempore? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit fugiat labore accusantium commodi tempore eaque veniam excepturi nulla dicta magni, aut saepe facilis cum consequuntur est inventore itaque laudantium corrupti.</div>


      <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you provide the code and examples on what is happening and please attach some images

Comment: Rather than screenshots of the code, set this up in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).  Much easier to experiment with there.

Comment: I added the code and an example of an ease-in-out transition @Souad

Comment: Thanks i'll look into jsfiddle I don't know anything about it.

Comment: Simply edit and CTRL-M to get a code snippet right here in your question that runs.  I will edit with a start if you like

Comment: Paste all hat code in and we will see if we can help - try to do it soon before your question gets closed with not enough detail

Comment: I provided the code for the 3 languages

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating the problem with much less code: https://jsfiddle.net/sd5yj1a0/ (If I'm understanding right, the desired-and-not-happening behavior is for the color change that happens on page load to not run the transition, while the checkbox still does)

Comment: yeah I wan't the checkbox to run the transition but not the page loads but since I'm using an i tag for the icon I don't know how I can make the same thing as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what that mass of CSS is attempting so for this answer, I removed it as not part of the question.  Rather than toggle a class, I decided to toggle a data attribute value and select by that.  We could have "lightblue", "dark", "light" etc.

I used a fake local storage - but again you can work that out in your code (it does not work on StackOverflow thus why I do it differently)

Now to back to your question: simply set the value in the data attribute (on the body in this case) before/on page load.  It should be great initially (it is just CSS) but then do whatever when you toggle it.

Just to be clear, I added the transition related CSS.

```js
const darkBtn = document.querySelector('.fas');

function fakeLocalGet(itemName) {
  const iholdstuff = document.querySelector('#i-hold-stuff');
  return iholdstuff.dataset[itemName];
}

function fakeLocalSet(itemName, itemValue) {
  const iholdstuff = document.querySelector('#i-hold-stuff');
  iholdstuff.dataset[itemName] = itemValue;
}
var toggleState = function(elem, one, two) {
  var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
  elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === one ? two : one);
};

darkBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let isDarkMode = (fakeLocalGet('dark') === "on");
  // console.log(isDarkMode);
  if (isDarkMode) {
    toggleState('body', 'dark', 'light');
    fakeLocalSet('dark', 'on');
  } else {
    toggleState('body', 'light', 'dark');
    fakeLocalSet('dark', 'off');
  }
});
// initially set to light (dark off)
fakeLocalSet('dark', "off");
//toggleState('body', 'dark', 'light');
let setDarkMode = fakeLocalGet('dark');
// Check dark mode is on or off on page reload
/*
if (setDarkMode === 'on') {
  darkMode();
}
*/
```

```css
#i-hold-stuff {
  display: none;
}

body[data-state=dark],
body[data-state=initial] {
  background-color: #888888;
}

body[data-state=dark] {
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

body[data-state=light] {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  transition: 0.75s ease-in-out;
}

.showme {
  border: solid #00ff00 1px;
  color: #FF0000:
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<body data-state="initial">
  <div id="i-hold-stuff"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden" />
      <label for="nav" class="nav-btn">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    </label>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">SITE</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Lofi.html">Lofi</a></li>
          <li><a href="League_Of_Legends.html">LoL</a></li>
          <li><a href="Tower_Of_God.html">ToG</a></li>
          <li><a href="card.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><i class="fas fa-moon fa-2x"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime vitae fugiat, velit, numquam totam vel sequi tempora, rerum nam earum repudiandae omnis consequuntur incidunt! Quam maxime quibusdam neque corporis tempore? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Impedit fugiat labore accusantium commodi tempore eaque veniam excepturi nulla dicta magni, aut saepe facilis cum consequuntur est inventore itaque laudantium corrupti.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I haven't learned javascript yet so I'll check how to make this work and hopefully it will solve my problem !

Comment: Note if you run this, initially it will do the transition here, but should not when you do it for real (put it on the sever initially.  You could have a third "initial" state with no transition for instance.  I think I will put that in just to show that.

Comment: Run the sample now, shows how to do initial > light > dark etc.

Comment: Answer works, but I think it would be a better answer if it was trimmed down to show only the parts that are necessary for the working dark/light toggle.